# Accesing the wso2 stratos services defined in the service-stubs file

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

From the wso2 stratos source files there is a 'service stubs' (wso2-stratos-1.5.1-src/service-stubs) section. Normally we can not access to these web services and after building the source the services are hidden. Is there a way to access to these web services outside of carbon api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to invoke these back end services directly?

As you may now, All the WSO2 products has a concept of Front end and back End. FE always talk to back end using a web service call. We use service stubs for that.

Stubs --> web service.

Therefore you can always access those back end services by directly calling the BE with your client. This article[1] describes such access instances with the relevant samples.

if you want to access these services as a tenant you can add /a/ to url

eg. services/a/amila.com/MessageBoxAdmin

[1] http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/08/messaging-eventing-soa